# destination host unreachable virtualbox

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machines, virtualbox, ping

Basically i am trying to implement this on this picture [image: architecture]

I have my static ips assigned more or less like this and i can ping from my internal network to my 2 ports in my router without any problems.

But for some reason when i try to use my external network to ping the router it gives me

> destination host unreachable

here are my configuration images : 
Router_1
[image: Router_1]
Router_2
[image: Router_2]
Internal VM
[image: Internal vm]
External VM
[image: External vm]

how can i accomplish this in a way all my vm's can ping each other?

Comment: How is the hypervisor configured?  It may be that the VMs are not virtually connected.  Also, consider not posting large screenshots when simply posting interface config...

Comment: how do i connect the virtual machines? i am using virtualbox

Comment: Yes.  How are the virtual interfaces configured in the hypervisor (virtualbox)?

Comment: router vm as 2 adapters both in ''bridged adapter'' one with the wlan0 and the other with eth0
the other machines only have one bridged adapter with wlan0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had a misconfiguration in my vm settings. changed the name of the connection from eth0 to wlan0 witch is exactly the name from the other vm